# Is there an editable textfield on flutter canvas

Tags: canvas, dart, flutter

I need a editable textfield on canvas.

Currently I using a textspan with textpainter to create the shown text.
And we need tap on the textspan to switch to editable text.

```
TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
  text: this.name,
);
TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
  text: span,
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  maxLines: 1,
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
tp.layout();
tp.paint(canvas,Offset(node.dx + 10.0, node.dy + 5.0),);
```

Does flutter support editable textfield on canvas?

Cross-link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24778

Comment: That's pretty unclear, but be aware of one thing: Everything in flutter is built around a canvas

Comment: Does TextField (https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/text-input) suit your needs?